# using EJB remote interfaces outside of Main

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.1

I have a hello-world style java ee application using maven3 glassfish3 and javaee6.

I have a simple session bean:

```
package com.mytest.beans;

import com.mytest.interfaces.HelloBeanRemote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class HelloBean implements HelloBeanRemote{

    @Override
    public String sayHello() {
        return "well hello there";
    }
}
```

it exposes a remote interface. this interface is in the same module but a different package.

```
package com.mytest.interfaces;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface HelloBeanRemote {

    public String sayHello();

}
```

I am using the maven-ejb-plugin to create an ejb-client artifact which my client module depends on.

I wrote this simple app-client

```
package com.mytest;

import com.mytest.interfaces.HelloBeanRemote;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 * Enterprise Application Client main class.
 *
 */
public class Main {

    @EJB
    private static HelloBeanRemote hb;

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
        JButton button = new JButton("i have not been pushed");
        pane.add(button);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        button.setText(hb.sayHello());
    }
}
```

this worked for me as expected. however when I changed my app-client to this:

```
package com.mytest;

import com.mytest.interfaces.HelloBeanRemote;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 * Enterprise Application Client main class.
 *
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
        MyButton button = new MyButton("i have not been pushed");
        pane.add(button);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

...

```
package com.mytest;

import com.mytest.interfaces.HelloBeanRemote;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.swing.JButton;


public class MyButton extends JButton implements ActionListener{

    @EJB
    private HelloBeanRemote hb;

    public MyButton(String string){
        super(string);
        addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        setText(hb.sayHello());
    }

}
```

this will not work as expected when I click the button.

Can someone please enlighten me!

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The glassfish development guide says:

> Annotation is supported for the main class and the optional callback
>   handler class in application clients.

So, either you inject the beans in the main class, and build some sort of singleton registry where all the classes will get a reference to the EJBs, or you use JNDI to get a reference to a bean, or you use some dependency injection framework (Spring, Guice, etc.) which will have its own injection rules and will use the registry or JNDI as a factory for the EJB references.